# Rails 3 on CentOS - problems with mysql2 gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So is anyone out there able to successfully run Rails 3.2 on CentOS ?  Here's the problem we're seeing:

```
[root@scglobal-web01 current]# rails c
/var/www/html/webapps/intl-custserv/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.15 but the client library is 5.0.92. (RuntimeError)
    from /var/www/html/webapps/intl-custserv/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

And here's some detailed info about our environment:

```
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.13, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1  
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.6.7 [ amd64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p358 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.2)
actionpack (3.2.2)
activemodel (3.2.2)
activerecord (3.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.2)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.0, 1.0.22)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.1)
json (1.6.5)
mail (2.4.3)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
passenger (3.0.11)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.2)
railties (3.2.2)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.1.15)
sass-rails (3.2.4)
sprockets (2.1.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.32)
uglifier (1.2.3)
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]#
```

Here's also where some (maybe) relevant files reside:

```
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# whereis mysql_config
mysql_config: /usr/bin/mysql_config /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# ls -al /usr/lib64/mysql
total 14988
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Mar  7 22:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 44 root root    24576 Mar  7 23:15 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   120260 May 11  2011 libmygcc.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15148296 May 11  2011 libmysqlclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Mar  7 22:59 libmysqlclient_r.a -> libmysqlclient.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    10000 May 11  2011 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Mar  7 22:20 plugin
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]#
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of mySQL installed?

Comment: That's a good thought!  I don't think we do though.  `[root@scglobal-web01 ~]# which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
[root@scglobal-web01 ~]#`

Comment: ```which``` would just show you the first bin that's found. You may have to do more digging.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same exact problem.

running on:

- CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- rvm and ruby 1.9.3

What I have reached so far is that mysql-devel package is for mysql 5.0.x instead of 5.5

I need to reinstall the gem with the new package. but i am unable to do that so far

the signs are

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.linuxwerk.com
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
 * updates: mirror.optimate-server.de
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:**5.1.69**-1.el6_4 will be installed
```

and after we get it installed. bundle install works well to install 0.3.13. and we're back to:

```
$rails c
...../gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.1.69 but the client library is 5.5.28. (RuntimeError)
```